# Rename specific files and move to proper directories (Batch? Powershell?)

Tags: powershell, batch, window

We have files (with no extension) that are dropped by clients in a shared directory:

```
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\BRSURVEY802DATA
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\BRSURVEYLOGINDATA
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\BRSURVEYLOGOUTDATA
```

Those files have to be renamed and moved to their proper directories as follows:

```
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\802\ORDDFILE_&DATE#&TIME#.802
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\SurveyLogin\ORDDFILE_&DATE#&TIME#.LOGIN
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\SurveyLogout\ORDDFILE_&DATE#&TIME#.LOGOUT
```

Any other files:

```
\\\Server\SharedDirectory\Rejected\ORDDFILE_&DATE#&TIME#.REJECTED
```

I tried the following, and it's working properly for one part:

```
! Setting time variables
@SET DATEFORMAT# ='YYYYMMDD'
@SET DATE# = SYS_DATE(DATEFORMAT#)
@SET TIMEFORMAT# = 'HHMMSS'
@SET TIME# = SYS_TIME(TIMEFORMAT#)

! Input directory values saved in VARA object
: PRINT 'SOURCEDIR = &ORDDFilesFromLocation#'
: PRINT '802DIR = &ORDDFilesToLocation802#'
: PRINT 'LOGINDIR = &ORDDFilesToLocationLogin#'
: PRINT 'LOGOUTDIR = &ORDDFilesToLocationLogout#'
: PRINT 'REJECTEDDIR = &ORDDFilesToLocationRejected#'

! Local variables
@SET INPUT802=&ORDDFilesFromLocation#BRSURVEY802DATA
@SET INPUTLOGIN=&ORDDFilesFromLocation#BRSURVEYLOGINDATA
@SET INPUTLOGOUT=&ORDDFilesFromLocation#BRSURVEYLOGOUTDATA

@SET OUTPUT802=&ORDDFilesToLocation802#ORDDFile_DATE#TIME#.802
@SET OUTPUTLOGIN=&ORDDFilesToLocationLogin#ORDDFile_DATE#TIME#.LOGIN
@SET OUTPUTLOGOUT=&ORDDFilesToLocationLogin#ORDDFile_DATE#TIME#.LOGOUT
@SET OUTPUTREJECTED=&ORDDFilesToLocationRejected#ORDDFile_DATE#TIME#.REJECTED

!! *** Rename and move files to destination folder ***
! 802
if exist %INPUT802% (
    for %%I in ("%INPUT802%") do move %%I "%OUTPUT802%"
)
! Login
if exist %INPUTLOGIN% (
    for %%I in ("%INPUTLOGIN%") do move %%I "%OUTPUTLOGIN%"
)
! Logout
if exist %INPUTLOGOUT% (
    for %%I in ("%INPUTLOGOUT%") do move %%I "%OUTPUTLOGOUT%"
)

ECHO End of Program
```

Now I have to deal with the other files that I have to move and rename as rejected.  Can somebody please help me with this ?

I tried the following based on your answers :

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableExtension

for /f useback^delims^= %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b "\\Fld6filer\brdProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\"`) do
     if /i "%%~ni" == "BRSURVEY802DATA" (
          move "%%~fi" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\802\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.802"
         )else if /i "%%~ni" == "BRSURVEYLOGINDATA" (
          move "%%~fi" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.LOGIN"
         )else if /i "%%~ni" == "BRSURVEYLOGOUTDATA" (
          move "%%~fi" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.LOGOUT"
         )else move "%%~fi" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.UNKNOWN"

endlocal
```

I get error message :  The syntax of the command is incorrect.

So I researched a bit and modified the code with echos to follow what was going on in the log :

```
 for /f %%i in ('dir /b  "\\Fld6filer\brdProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\"') do (
    if "%%~xi" == "BRSURVEY802DATA" do (
       echo I am in 
       move "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\BRSURVEY802DATA" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\802\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.802"
    )
    else if "%%~xi" == "BRSURVEYLOGINDATA" do (
       echo I am in Login
       move "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\BRSURVEYLOGINDATA" "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\LOGIN\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.LOGIN"
    )
    else if "%%~xi" == "BRSURVEYLOGOUTDATA" do (
       echo I am in Logout
       move "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\BRSURVEYLOGOUTDATA"  "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\LOGOUT\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.LOGOUT"
    )
    else do (
       ECHO I am in Unknown
       move "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\*.*"  "\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\REJECTED\ORDDFILE_20230319215412.UNKNOWN"
    )  
 )
```

This worked as expected.  However, the log contains messages that I don't like at all, and I don't understand why this is happening...

```
I am in 
        1 file(s) moved.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
I am in 
The system cannot find the file specified.
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I am in Login
        1 file(s) moved.
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I am in Logout
        1 file(s) moved.
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I am in Unknown
\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\BLABLABLA
        1 file(s) moved.
```

There are 4 directories and 4 files in the source directory to start with.  It looks like all the objects are going through the first IF statement.  Also, the ELSEs are not recognized, but the job is being done in the end.  Any idea ?

Mylene

Comment: And what should happen, if there are multiple rejected files?

Comment: What I would ideally like to do is loop through the directory and deal with the file one at a time using case statement.  The date/time stamp format is "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" so it wouldn't cause any issues.  But I can't figure out how to do it in batch, and this has to be completed ASAP ! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bath
@echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_dt=%%~i" 

set "_date_time=%_dt:~0,4%%_dt:~4,2%%_dt:~6,2%%_dt:~8,2%%_dt:~10,4%"
pushd "\\Fld6filer\brdProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\" || endlocal && goto :eOf
 
set "_login=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.LOGIN"
set "_logout=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.LOGOUT"

set "_802Dir=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\802\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.802"
set "_unknown=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.UNKNOWN"

for /f useback^delims^= %%i in (`dir /a-d /b
   `)do if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurvey802data" (
         echo/I am in .802
         move "%%~fi" "%_802Dir%"
        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGINdata" (
         echo/I am in .Login
         move "%%~fi" "%_login%"
        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGOUTdata" (
         echo/I am in .Logout
         move "%%~fi" "%_logout%"
        )else echo/I am in .unknowm && move "%%~fi" "%_unknown%"

endlocal & popd
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 05 | echo\End of Program
```

---

You can try:

```bath
for /f Loop (your files)do if 802 (
  command ...
 )else if Login (
  command ...
 )else if Logout (
  command ...
 )else command ..        // ! Rejected
```

---

**Obs.1:** You can test and verify the behavior of the command just by adding **`echo\Move Command`** and nothing will be moved:

```bath
@echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_dt=%%~i" 

set "_date_time=%_dt:~0,4%%_dt:~4,2%%_dt:~6,2%%_dt:~8,2%%_dt:~10,4%"
pushd "\\Fld6filer\brdProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\" || endlocal && goto :eOf
 
set "_login=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.LOGIN"
set "_logout=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.LOGOUT"

set "_802Dir=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\802\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.802"
set "_unknown=\\fld6filer\BRDProduction_SurveyFiles$\Incoming\ORDD\DEV\ORDDFILE_%_date_time%.UNKNOWN"

for /f useback^delims^= %%i in (`dir /a-d /b
   `)do if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurvey802data" (
         echo/I am in .802
         echo\move "%%~fi" "%_802Dir%"
        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGINdata" (
         echo/I am in .Login
         echo\move "%%~fi" "%_login%"
        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGOUTdata" (
         echo/I am in .Logout
         echo\move "%%~fi" "%_logout%"
        )else echo/I am in .unknowm && echo\move "%%~fi" "%_unknown%"

endlocal & popd
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 05 | echo\End of Program
```

---

**Obs.2:** I'm not sure I understand your question, precisely as it relates to variable definitions and path compositions.

---

> *However, the log contains messages that I don't like at all*
> You can omit the standard output and/or the error **[output in several ways](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)**:
>
> ```bath
>  stdout  =  1  Text output
>  stderr  =  2  Error text output
>  ----------------------------------
>  command   >nul
>  command   >nul 2>&1
>  command   >nul 2>nul
>  command  1>nul
>  command  2>nul
>  command  2>&1
>  command  1>nul 2>&1
>  command  1>nul 2>nul
>  
>  for /f useback^delims^= %%i in (`dir /a-d /b
>    `)do if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurvey802data" 1>nul (
>          move "%%~fi" "%_802Dir%"
>        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGINdata" 1>nul (
>          move "%%~fi" "%_login%"
>        )else if /i "%%~ni" == "brsurveyLOGOUTdata" 1>nul (
>          move "%%~fi" "%_logout%"
>        )else move "%%~fi" "%_unknown%" 1>nul
> ```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[`Pushd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**
- **[`Popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**
- **[`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
- **[`FindStr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
- **[`For Loop /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
- **[`For /F Loop /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  - **[`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  - **`|`**, **`<`**, **`>`**, **`2>`**, **`2>&1`**, etc.
- **[Split string into substrings based on delimiter by Sponge Belly / DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)**

Comment: You were lucky, your first and second editions were difficult to understand names/values ​​of variables and paths, because you used strange/different syntax than what is used in cmd/batch...

Comment: Sorry ! English is not my primary language ! Thank you for helping me out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't fully understand some nuances of your script.

But I believe you could add this to the end of script, to move rejected files.

```
@SET SOURCEDIR=&ORDDFilesFromLocation#
for %%I in ("%SOURCEDIR%") do (
    move %%I "%OUTPUTREJECTED%"
    : Since name already used - we need to regenerate name with new timestamp
    : to guarantie differnce in timestamp - sleep for 1 seccond
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
    @SET OUTPUTREJECTED=&ORDDFilesToLocationRejected#ORDDFile_DATE#TIME#.REJECTED
)
```